# html Sementics, have no h1 header in a document

Tags: html

Is it semantically correct to have no h1 header in a web page, suppose i decided to have an image with the page logo and title used instead of having the h1 header element, is that acceptable?

Comment: The image *could* semantically be your H1.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to use image of logo instead of text version as your logo may be (and usually indeed is) complex. so it's fine. Remember however to use alt attribute for images explaining it.

I think that there is no requirement that says *'yes you NEED to use h1 tag on your page'*

Comment: okay so i decided to use an image for the page logo, the new question now is do i need to wrap it inside the <figure> element? I read that the figure is used for content such as code, images, etc that can be used as reference for some idea that is being discussed in the main flow, and if the figure were to be removed it would not affect the meaning of the content in the main flow. What about in my case? can i look at my page's logo as a figure? if not then what do i wrap my img element with?